# How to overlay text on image programmatically

Tags: android

I have a image placed in the relative layout. How can i place a small image over the background image and two text view side by side next to the image. Any help will be really appreciated. The only thing is I want to do this programmatically. I have tried doing it the following way but for some reason the textview appears on the top left of the screen. I want it appear on the imagebutton.

```
LinearLayout LinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this); 
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams;  

Button[] btn = new Button[1];   
btn[0] = new Button(this);
btn[0].setId(1);
btn[0].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
btn[0].setText("text");        
btn[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_grey);
btn[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));


relativeLayoutParams = new     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT | RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);

relativeLayoutParams.setMargins(20, 20, 15, 15);

relativeLayout.addView(btn[0], relativeLayoutParams);

ImageButton[] Imgbtn = new ImageButton[10];
Imgbtn[0] = new ImageButton(this);
Imgbtn[0].setId(2);   
Imgbtn[0].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.box_round_corners); 
Imgbtn[0].setMaxHeight(200);
Imgbtn[0].setClickable(true);

relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,btn[0].getId());
relativeLayoutParams.height = 100;    
relativeLayoutParams.setMargins(15, 0, 15, 10);
Imgbtn[0].setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);

relativeLayout.addView(Imgbtn[0], relativeLayoutParams);

TextView[] txtview = new TextView[10];
txtview[0] = new TextView(this);
txtview[0].setId(3);
txtview[0].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
txtview[0].setText("text");  

relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                                       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

// relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT | RelativeLayout.ALIGN_TOP);

```
relativeLayoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,Imgbtn[0].getId());
relativeLayoutParams.height = 20;    
relativeLayoutParams.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
txtview[0].setLayoutParams(relativeLayoutParams);

relativeLayout.addView(txtview[0], relativeLayoutParams);


android.widget.ScrollView ScrollV = new ScrollView(this); 
ScrollV.addView( relativeLayout, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
addContentView(ScrollV, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: *I want to do this programmatically* => Yes sure but first [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: @PareshMayani I have edited my question please have a look

Answer (score 0):

try to set your views LayoutParams with setLayoutParams() method;

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,height);
lp.topMargin=//what is your desired y coordinate
lp.leftMargin=//what is your desired x coordinate
lp.gravity=Gravity.NO_GRAVITY;
view.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

FrameLayout is better choise for overlaying purposes in my opinion.

Comment: I agree.  This is exactly the use case for `FrameLayout`.